# Is sub-level set of a continuous functional closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $F[f]$ be a continuous functional on set of continuos functions defined on the interval $[a,b]$. With the norm defined $|f|=\max_{ a \le x \le b} |f(x)|$.

How to show that the following sub-level set is closed:
\begin{align*}
S=\{f : F[f] \le c \}
\end{align*}

Also, if $F[f]$ is concave in $f$ is $S$ convex or not?

I have no idea how to show that $S$ is closed. But the proof for (non)convexity should be using concavity of $F$
\begin{align*}
F[\alpha f_1 +(1-\alpha) f_2] \ge \alpha F[f_1] +(1-\alpha) F[f_2]
\end{align*}
but than how do we proceed from here?
Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** Thanks to Paul and Crostul  I can show that $S$ is closed.

Comment: To show that S is closed, show that the limit of any convergent sequence $f_n$ which are each in S is also in S.

Comment: HINT: $S = F^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ and $(-\infty, c]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $F$ is continuous, $S$ is closed.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks. Got its because if $F$ is continuous implies that  the preimage of a closed set in rage  is closed in the domain. What about convexity of $S$, can we say anything about that?

Answer (score 2):

The set $S$ is closed because $F$ is continuous and $S=F^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,c)\bigr)$.

However, $S$ doesn't have to be convex. Suppose that $a=-1$ and that $b=1$. Define$$F[f]=-\int_{-1}^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$Then $F$ is concave. Now take $c=-1$, $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x)=-x$. Then $f_1,f_2\in S$. But $\frac12(f_1+f_2)\notin S$, because $\int_{-1}^1\frac12(f_1+f_2)=0$ and $0>-1$.